# Search: Reinstating a "search result removal" removed item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

It's possible to remove search results using the "Remove Search Result" feature in the Search SSA, however I can't see any technique to update the setting to remove a previously removed result (eg undo the 'remove' action).

Reference:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/jj219587.aspx#proc2

In short - we are looking for a way to undo / reverse a "removal" of a search result.  It appears as though you can permanently remove a search result but can't re-enable it to be viewable again.  Any thoughts welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: (SharePoint 15.0.4571.1502)

- If content is re-crawled (eg full crawl, or this item is changed during an incremental crawl) then the item will re-appear in the search results
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/jj219587.aspx does not mention this behaviour.
- The same behaviour occurs for either of the two remove functions

  - Remove an item from the search index
  - Remove an item from the search results
- In short: while these two processes remove the items from the search results, unless crawling is also paused the items will re-appear during the next crawl of the content types.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your crawl rules. Last time I did this it also created a crawl rule to exclude the item from subsequent crawls. just remove the rule.